# SwiftUI's onAppear() and onDisappear() called multiple times and inconsistently on Xcode 12.1

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I've come across some strange behavior with SwiftUI's `onAppear()` and `onDisappear()` events. I need to be able to reliably track when a view is visible to the user, disappears, and any other subsequent appear/disappear events (the use case is tracking impressions for mobile analytics).

I was hoping to leverage the `onAppear()` and `onDisappear()` events associated with swiftUI views, but I'm not seeing consistent behavior when using those events. The behavior can change depending on view modifiers as well as the simulator on which I run the app.

In the example code listed below, I would expect that when `ItemListView2` appears, I would see the following printed out in the console:

```
button init
button appear
```

And on the iPhone 8 simulator, I see exactly that.

However, on an iPhone 12 simulator, I see:

```
button init
button appear
button disappear
button appear
```

Things get even weirder when I enable the `listStyle` view modifier:

```
button init
button appear
button disappear
button appear
button disappear
button appear
button appear
```

The iPhone 8, however remains consistent and produces the expected result.

I should also note that in no case, did the Button ever seem to disappear and re-appear to the eye.

These inconsistencies are also not simulator only issues, i noticed them on devices as well.

I need to reliably track these appear/disappear events. For example I'd need to know when a cell in a list appears (scrolled into view) or disappears (scrolled out of view) or when, say a user switches tabs.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior?  To me this seems like a bug in SwiftUI, but I'm not certain as I've not used SwiftUI enough to trust myself to discern a programmer error from an SDK error. If any of you have noticed this, did you find a good work-around / fix?

Thanks,

- Norm

```
// Sample code referenced in explanation
// Using Xcode Version 12.1 (12A7403) and iOS 14.1 for all simulators
import SwiftUI

struct ItemListView2: View {

    let items = ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3", "Cell 4"]

    var body: some View {
        ListingView(items: items)
    }
}

private struct ListingView: View {
    let items: [String]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(
                footer:
                    FooterButton()
                    .onAppear { print("button appear") }
                    .onDisappear { print("button disappear") }
            ) {
                ForEach(items) { Text($0) }
            }
        }
//      .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}

private struct FooterButton: View {
    init() {
        print("button init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) { Text("Button")  }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe `.onAppear()` is fired when the view state update is complete. If the view graph is rebuilt after because of additional state updates, that could account for multiple .onAppear behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In SwiftUI you don't control when items in a `List` *appear* or *disappear*. The view graph is managed internally by SwiftUI and views may appear/disappear at any time.

You can, however, attach the `onAppear` / `onDisappear` modifiers to the outermost view:

```
List {
    Section(footer: FooterButton()) {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { 
            Text($0) 
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
.onAppear { print("list appear") }
.onDisappear { print("list disappear") }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this UIKit approach. Similar behavior continues to exist under iOS 14.

```
protocol RemoteActionRepresentable: AnyObject {
    func remoteAction()
}

struct UIKitAppear: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let action: () -> Void
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIAppearViewController {
       let vc = UIAppearViewController()
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: UIAppearViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(action: self.action)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: RemoteActionRepresentable {
        
        var action: () -> Void
        
        init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.action = action
        }
        
        func remoteAction() {
            action()
        }
    }
}

class UIAppearViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: RemoteActionRepresentable?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.addSubview(UILabel())
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        delegate?.remoteAction()
    }
}

extension View {
    func onUIKitAppear(_ perform: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(UIKitAppear(action: perform))
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var body: some View {
    MyView().onUIKitAppear {
        print("UIViewController did appear")
   }
}
```

Comment: work like a charm, still UIKit is more stable then SwiftUI.